# How do I set an http-interface password on VLC 2.x?

Tags: vlc-media-player, password-protection, ubuntu-12.04

I'd like to set up a password for my VLC's HTTP interface server. I'm using VLC 2.x on Ubuntu Precise. How do I set this up? I see numerous mentions online of this being possible.

Ideally, I'd like the username and password to apply to the whole interface, not just files. However, I did find that [documentation](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Play_HowTo/Building_Pages_for_the_HTTP_Interface#Introduction) that creating a `.access` file in a directory will protect the contents of that directory. The docs say you need only `echo "foo:bar" > .access` in the directory and it'll work. I can't even get that to work through.

Comment: I'll second this - I can't get this to work for anything, and by default you can use the web interface to browse every single file on the computer... which is a pretty large security hole.

Answer (score 0):

In VLC 2.0.x only IP based control is possible.

In VLC 2.1.x and later, the option [`http-password][1]` as added for this purpose.